# How to disable WebCam diode programmatically

Tags: c#, c++, programming-languages, winforms-interop

In my laptop (Dell) strong blue diode light while WebCam use is annoying me.

I was thinking to disable it.  Do you know any library or method to turn off this diode light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done this, and it is completely possible without hardware modification on MOST (if not all) Dell webcams compatible with the Dell webcam software.

With older Dell Webcam Center software and drivers (~pre 2008), there is a setting which controls the LED during motion capture and it can be easily changed in the GUI.

For the newer Dell Webcam Central software, I had to use IDA/Cheat Engine/Hex Editor to manually debug and patch the driver DLL file.  But this IS possible and only requires changing a couple of jmp instructions.

Comment: Hi SevenPath, I'm not so "desperate" to use some hexeditor and change instruction in assembly language (heh, SoftIce times... ;)) but thanks for your time and comment :)

Comment: No problem, you are welcome. If anyone is looking for a general starting point or hint on debugging/reverse engineering LED controls, start by observing that if/when it is possible to make the light "blink" on/off whilst still recording then you know for a fact that the code running at that moment is the code which can control the light.